# coremltools produces a lot of inputs for xgboost model

Tags: xgboost, coreml, coremltools

I'm doing conversion from xgboost to coreml in coremltools tools with python, but it produces n separate inputs (instead of single input array) for coreml model.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue last week, and I could not find a proper solution to fix that problem. I believe that when I am writing this, there is no way to handle a large number of inputs properly.

In my case, the model expected a bit more than 1000 inputs (named `f0`, `f1`, `f2`, ...) as I flattened some image features to train the boosting algorithm on that. I found the only workaround was writing a short python snippet to generate the string to copy/paste into XCode. For instance, in my case, the array with the inputs to the CoreML model is named `stackedFeatures` and, as mentioned, the features are called `f0`, `f1`, `f2`, ...

```py
def save_swift_input_str(model):
    path_to_save_txt = os.path.join(path_to_save_model, "predict_args.txt")
    text_file = open(path_to_save_txt, "w")
    feature_names = model.feature_names
    feature_list_swift_name = "stackedFeatures["
    for idx, feature_name in enumerate(feature_names):
        text_file.write('{}: {},'.format(feature_name, feature_list_swift_name + str(idx) + "]"))
    text_file.close()
```

Then by copy/pasting the content of this file into the class that handles the model input like that:

```swift
let modelInput = ModelInput(f0: stackedFeatures[0],f1: stackedFeatures[1],f2: stackedFeatures[2],f3: stackedFeatures[3],f4: stackedFeatures[4],f5: stackedFeatures[5],f6: stackedFeatures[6],f7: stackedFeatures[7],f8: stackedFeatures[8], ...)
```

I could run the prediction using CoreML on my device using this code:

```swift
guard let modelOutput = try? model.prediction(input: model_input) else {
                            fatalError("Unexpected runtime error.")
                        }
```

I hope this helps! I would also be curious if someone found a more elegant solution to solve this problem!